# Unparallel pre-treatment trends in synthetic control method

Tags: synthetic-controls

I'm trying to run a synthetic control model, and have a general question.

My data contains 201 localities over 9 years - 8 pre-treatment and 1 post-treatment.
In the model, I include several socio-demographic variables (e.g., total population, mean age, male ratio, mean income, etc.), as well as the outcome variable, which is crime.
The problem is that whatever I'm trying, the trends of the treated and synthetic units are far from being parallel. The trend of the synthetic unit is "smooth", while the line of the treated unit goes up and down.

Is there something particular that can cause this? Should I try using more time points (e.g. months), or including more predictors?

Thanks!